# Cant add Integer to a Arraylist with Generic type <? extends Number>

Tags: java, generics

I cant add `new Integer(1)` like this:

```
List<? extends Number> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numList.add(new Integer(1));
```

but i can do it this way:

```
List<? super Number> numList = new ArrayList<>();
    numList.add(new Integer(1));
```

but if we instantiate List like thisnew ArrayList<**Integer**>();

it will not work.

---

as i understand, this `<? extends Number>` means that i can insert any class, that extends this, any child class(Float, Double, Integer etc).
This `<? super Number>` means that i can insert Number and its ancestors(None, Object class should fit)
Please tell me what im not understanding in Generics.

Maybe such code is not recommended at all?

Comment: What do you think should happen if you try to add an Integer to a List of some unknown type which might not be Integer?

Comment: Also duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4343202/5221149)

Comment: its known type, a subclass of Number.

Comment: @Igor yes, it can be *any* subclass of `Number`, including `Long`, `Float` or `BigDecimal`. In any of these cases, you couldn't add an `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks for link to original question, there is a good explanation!

Comment: @Clashsoft I thought it will work like Number n = new Integer(1);
 we can set any of childs of Number and access only methods of Number interface.